# Fix unmet dependecies

Tags: apt, dependencies

I continue to deal with apt. After unsuccesful apt-offline use I've got a message, that there are errors with broken count.
I ran `sudo apt-get check` and got output:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 237-3ubuntu10.33) but 237-3ubuntu10.39 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 237-3ubuntu10.33) but 237-3ubuntu10.39 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But if I follow this advise, I see a long list of modules which will be removed (97), including `init initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core plymouth plymouth-label`, etc.
I did it once some time ago, broke my installation and was forced to reinstall Ubunte, so I think that execute this command is bad idea.

How can I fix this unmet dependencies without complete destroy my installation?
Thank you!

**Edited**

Okey, it's turned out very simple in my case.
On my offline Ubuntu I executed

`sudo apt-get check`

and got a list of packages with unmet dependecies.

Next on my online machine (actually, Win 10 Pro with Ubuntu 18.04.4 as WSL) I executed this command (from https://www.ostechnix.com/download-packages-dependencies-locally-ubuntu/)

`$ apt-get download $(apt-rdepends package_wih_unmet | grep -v "^ " | sed 's/debconf-2.0/debconf/g')`

(where `package_wih_unmet` is one of packeges from the list I've got on the previous step) in folder I've created for this purpose (for example, '~/python-crypto/'), for every package from the list above.

Next I copyed downloaded files to flash and on offline Ubunut simply ran `sudo dpkg -i *` in this folders.

For several iterations I've restored my System in unmet dependecies manner.

But I had to take my notebook with modem for efficiency.

Comment: A quick look at one item (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libudev1) shows the installed version is correct; what version of `udev` have you installed? and available  ie. `apt-cache policy udev`  (This is based on assumption you're using 18.04 LTS on *amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x* sd you didn't specify)

Comment: Here is output:
`udev:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.33
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.33
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.33 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
`

I'm newbie in Linux, sorry.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, it allows greater formatting and is far easier to read.  Your detail looks out of date, The correct bionic package available is 237-3ubuntu10.38 and not 10.33 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=udev); so I'd suggest you `sudo apt update`  and read for errors, and correct/expected output, if everything looks okay you could then try again (or `sudo apt -f install`) but your results for the `apt-cache policy` are very very old.

Comment: This question is consequence of this situation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213424/apt-offline-install-produces-keyring-error
The output was as this:
```udev:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.33
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.33
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.33 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: This question is consequence of this situation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213424/apt-offline-install-produces-keyring-error
Briefly, I have Ubuntu system on absolutely offline computer. It's located in private network and I can't use any modem. So, I try update it with apt-offline, which (as I understand) doesn't work properly om Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (I've got it a couple of weeks ago from official site). Now I'm going to install some dev software, but I fear, that my system is in  inconsistent state.
Unfortunately I can't use online options of apt.
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Another solution would be:

```
sudo apt purge libsystemd0 libudev1
sudo apt install libsystemd0=237-3ubuntu10.33
sudo apt install libudev1=237-3ubuntu10.33
```

Comment: this answer doesn't work